# filtering using Rank() and Index() not changing the total

Tags: tableau-api

I am calculating efficiency for mechanics using the `sum of hours worked` divided by the sum of hours we charged the customer as per work order. Using tableau's `total` from the analytics pane, it gives me the weighted average of their efficiency (whereas the `average` function is skewed as it only takes into account the final efficiency rating.

When I use index() or rank() to create a filter to remove individual work orders, the total doesn't change.

How can I remove work orders and change the total without having to use a filter that selects individual work orders?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using LOD with specific condition in the if statement before you take the average or do any calculation.
Since the fixed calculation will take the data directly from the table. The number will only changed with filter when you put the parameter in the first part of LOD. 
A quick example:

```
{Fixed [parameter]: AVG(IF [work orders] == condition then [weighted average] END)}
```